# Returning org-babel results from an asynchronous call

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

I'm currently experimenting with moving more of my development workflow into org-mode so I can keep better track of what testing I've done. However some of the steps involve asynchronous calls to RPC services. The following snippet shows the problem:

```
#+name: simple-async-example
#+begin_src emacs-lisp 
  (async-start
     ;; What to do in the child process
     (lambda ()
       (message "This is a test")
       (sleep-for 3)
       222)

     ;; What to do when it finishes
     (lambda (result)
       (format "Async process done - result should be 222: %s" result)))
#+end_src

#+RESULTS: simple-async-example
: #<process emacs>
```

As you can see the result comes from the first task. What I need to do is append the actual result once the processing has been completed. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Apart from the title, it isn't actually clear what your question is. Answering the title, I think this question comes up often on the Org email list, and the answer is "not currently supported".

Comment: @mankoff: OK I've re-worded and simplified the question to try an make it easier to follow. Is that better?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_Working_Example why not have a 3-line bash script that returns something asynch that anyone can run/test/understand?

Comment: @mankoff: well bash is inherently synchronous isn't it? I did wrap all the build and upload stuff into one script to simplify it but the LAVA job submission is something that happens asynchronously within emacs.

Comment: @mankoff: How's the new elisp only example?

Comment: I think that is a great example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK Solving for the (async) example I've come up with this hack. It would be nice if I could automatically get the name of the source block rather than having to repeat it as a var.

```
** Post-modify the org-result
#+name: simple-async-with-post-modify
#+begin_src emacs-lisp :var this-buffer=(buffer-name (current-buffer)) this-name="simple-async-with-post-modify"
  (async-start
     ;; What to do in the child process
   `(lambda ()
     (message "This is a test")
     (sleep-for 3)
     ,(async-inject-variables "this-buffer")
     ,(async-inject-variables "this-name")
     (list
        (cons 'buffer this-buffer)
        (cons 'name this-name)
        (cons 'result 222)))

     ;; What to do when it finishes
   (lambda (result)
     (let ((buf (cdr (assoc 'buffer result)))
           (name (cdr (assoc 'name result)))
           (res (cdr (assoc 'result result))))
       (save-excursion
         (with-current-buffer buf
           (org-babel-goto-named-result name)
           (next-line)
           (goto-char (org-babel-result-end))
           (org-babel-insert-result (format "we got: %s" res)))))))
#+end_src

#+RESULTS: simple-async-with-post-modify
: #<process emacs>
: we got: 222
```

Comment: Hi. There is a [post by John Kitchin](http://kitchingroup.cheme.cmu.edu/blog/2015/11/20/Asynchronously-running-python-blocks-in-org-mode/) discussing a prototype solution for python code blocks that might be interesting to you.