# Referring to the org-babel src block name from within the script

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

This is tangentially related to my previous question on [dealing with asynchronous babel scripts](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/2411/returning-org-babel-results-from-an-asynchronous-call). Currently I have to manually specify the name of the src block the babel function is in:

```
#+name: elisp-block-name
#+begin_src emacs-lisp :var src="elisp-block-name"
(format "My src-block is %s" src)
#+end_src

#+RESULTS: elisp-block-name
: My src-block is elisp-block-name
```

Obviously this is prone to error so it would be nice to generate it programmaticaly. Is there any environment/variables always passed to tangled block that indicates this or do I need to just call some elisp for my :var block?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the **org-babel-get-src-block-info** function. I add a few examples to show that it indeed yields back the name of the block that is executing the code, even if called by other blocks.

I first define a block echoing its src block name

```
#+NAME: blockA
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp :results value
  (format "I am %s" (nth 4 (org-babel-get-src-block-info)))
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS: blockA
: I am blockA
```

Now I use the org-sbe function to call blockA from within the lisp code
of another block. The code running in blockA correctly identifies itself
as blockA.

```
#+NAME: blockB
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp :results value
(org-sbe blockA)
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS: blockB
: I am blockA
```

Org mode CALL syntax also yields the correct result...

```
#+CALL: blockB() :results value

#+RESULTS:
: I am blockA
```

... as does running the code in table formulas

```
#+NAME: tableA
| col1        | col2        |
|-------------+-------------|
| I am blockA | I am blockA |
#+TBLFM: @2$1='(org-sbe blockA)::@2$2='(org-sbe blockB)
```

Answer (score 4):

I was not able to use `org-babel-get-src-block-info` to declare a variable from the header line. It did work using `org-element-context` however:

```
#+NAME: a-name
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp :var block-name=(org-element-property :name (org-element-context))
  block-name
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS: a-name
: a-name
```

Calling that source code block from somewhere else results in the variable being set with the name from the new context:

```
#+NAME: another-name
#+CALL: a-name()

#+RESULTS: another-name
: another-name
```

If the code block is called without setting `#+NAME:`, the variable will be an empty string or `nil`.

```
#+CALL: a-name()

#+RESULTS:
```

This is different from the accepted answer but might be what some people are looking for.